# filter info from json file and display pdf via link

Tags: javascript, html, json

i have a uni project to make a progressive web app. I am trying to make a very simple app for pdf bus timetable viewer that will filter data out of a list and present the required pdf document in application.

I have collated all the bus info into spreadsheet and converted that into a json file that can be read/ displays on the index page as a table.

I want the user to be able to filter this list by column header and either enter in text/ number to query find/ search list to find the bus they want then have app display the appropriate pdf.

How can I do I achieve this?

I have looked into parsing the data, but want more info on how I might get it to work.

essentially I have buttons I want to link to the json data,(find by: bus number, route, start, stops, finish) when one is clicked it will show all results for that column from the table only and then add additional filters for user to input search or choose from list.

below is what I currently have in my idex page:

here is a sample of the data im working with:

```
{
"busTimes":
[
    {
        "Bus":"Bus",
        "Route":"Route",
        "Start":"Start",
        "Stop1":"Stop1",
        "Stop2":"Stop2",
        "Stop3":"Stop3",
        "Stop4":"Stop4",
        "Stop5":"Stop5",
        "Finish":"Finish",
        "Times":"Times",
        "Maps":"Maps"
    },
    {
        "Bus":"1",
        "Route":"Casuarina (Hospital Precinct)",
        "Start":"Casuarina",
        "Stop1":"Hospital Precinct",
        "Stop2":"Tiwi",
        "Stop3":"Brinkin",
        "Stop4":"Nakara",
        "Stop5":"NO STOP",
        "Finish":"Casuarina",
        "Times":"https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0009/159309/route-1-public-bus-timetable.pdf",
        "Maps":"https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/159308/route-1-public-bus-map.pdf"
    },
    {
        "Bus":"2",
        "Route":"Casuarina ",
        "Start":"Casuarina ",
        "Stop1":"Wanguri",
        "Stop2":"Lyons",
        "Stop3":"Leanyer",
        "Stop4":"Wulagi",
        "Stop5":"Wagaman",
        "Finish":"Casuarina",
        "Times":"https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0003/159312/route-2-public-bus-timetable.pdf",
        "Maps":"https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0019/159310/route-2-public-bus-map.pdf"
    },
    {
        "Bus":"3",
        "Route":"Casuarina",
        "Start":"Casuarina",
        "Stop1":"Alawa",
        "Stop2":"Jingili",
        "Stop3":"Marrara",
        "Stop4":"Moil",
        "Stop5":"Anula",
        "Finish":"Casuarina",
        "Times":"https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/159320/route-3-public-bus-timetable.pdf",
        "Maps":"https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/159317/route-3-public-bus-map.pdf"
    },
```

}

```
<!-- gets json data and puts it on page -->

<script>
    $(function() {


        var busTimes = [];

        $.getJSON('bustimes.json',
            function(data) {
                $.each(data.busTimes, function(i, f) {
                    var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.Bus + "</td>" +
                        "<td>" + f.Route + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Start + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Stop1 + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Stop2 + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Stop3 + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Stop4 + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Stop5 + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.Finish + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                    $(tblRow).appendTo("#buses tbody");
                });

            });

    });
</script>

<!-- button section to filter data -->
        <div class="menuSection" id="findBus">
            <p> find bus timetable by:</p>
            <ul>
                <li> <button  id="bus_number"> bus number </button> </li>
                <li> <button  id="bus_route"> bus route </button> </li>
                <li> <button  id="bus_start"> where the bus starts from  </button> </li>
                <li> <button id="bus_stop"> where the bus stops </button> </li>
                <li> <button id="bus_finish"> where the bus finishes     </button> </li>
            </ul>

        </div>

<!-- section to show the table -->
        <div class="mainSection">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <p>SEARCH RESULTS:</p>
                <div class="list">
                    <table id="buses" border="2">

                        <thead>
                            <th>Bus</th>
                            <th>Route</th>
                            <th>Start</th>
                            <th>Stop 1</th>
                            <th>Stop 2</th>
                            <th>Stop 3</th>
                            <th>Stop 4</th>
                            <th>Stop 5</th>
                            <th>Finish</th>
                            <th>Times</th>
                            <th>Maps</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple implementation using `hide` and `show` function. You need to use the attribute selector to determine which `tr` to hide and show.

```js
let data = {
  "busTimes": [{
      "Bus": "Bus",
      "Route": "Route",
      "Start": "Start",
      "Stop1": "Stop1",
      "Stop2": "Stop2",
      "Stop3": "Stop3",
      "Stop4": "Stop4",
      "Stop5": "Stop5",
      "Finish": "Finish",
      "Times": "Times",
      "Maps": "Maps"
    },
    {
      "Bus": "1",
      "Route": "Casuarina (Hospital Precinct)",
      "Start": "Casuarina",
      "Stop1": "Hospital Precinct",
      "Stop2": "Tiwi",
      "Stop3": "Brinkin",
      "Stop4": "Nakara",
      "Stop5": "NO STOP",
      "Finish": "Casuarina",
      "Times": "https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0009/159309/route-1-public-bus-timetable.pdf",
      "Maps": "https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/159308/route-1-public-bus-map.pdf"
    },
    {
      "Bus": "2",
      "Route": "Casuarina ",
      "Start": "Casuarina ",
      "Stop1": "Wanguri",
      "Stop2": "Lyons",
      "Stop3": "Leanyer",
      "Stop4": "Wulagi",
      "Stop5": "Wagaman",
      "Finish": "Casuarina",
      "Times": "https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0003/159312/route-2-public-bus-timetable.pdf",
      "Maps": "https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0019/159310/route-2-public-bus-map.pdf"
    },
    {
      "Bus": "3",
      "Route": "Casuarina",
      "Start": "Casuarina",
      "Stop1": "Alawa",
      "Stop2": "Jingili",
      "Stop3": "Marrara",
      "Stop4": "Moil",
      "Stop5": "Anula",
      "Finish": "Casuarina",
      "Times": "https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/159320/route-3-public-bus-timetable.pdf",
      "Maps": "https://nt.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0008/159317/route-3-public-bus-map.pdf"
    }
  ]
};

$.each(data.busTimes, function(i, f) {
  var tblRow = `<tr> 
                <td data-bus=${f.Bus}>${f.Bus}</td>
                <td>${f.Route}</td>
                <td>${f.Start}</td>
                <td>${f.Stop1}</td>
                <td>${f.Stop2}</td>
                <td>${f.Stop3}</td>
                <td>${f.Stop4}</td>
                <td>${f.Stop5}</td>
                <td>${f.Finish}</td>
            </tr>`

  $(tblRow).appendTo("#buses tbody");
});

$('#bus_number').keyup(function() {
  // console.log($(this).val())
  if ($(this).val()) {
    $('#buses tbody tr').hide();
    $('#buses tbody td[data-bus*=' + $(this).val() + ']').parent().show();
  } else {
    $('#buses tbody tr').show();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="menuSection" id="findBus">
  <p> find bus timetable by:</p>
  <ul>
    <li> <input type="text" placeholder="Search by bus number" id="bus_number" /> </li>
    <li> <button id="bus_route"> bus route </button> </li>
    <li> <button id="bus_start"> where the bus starts from  </button> </li>
    <li> <button id="bus_stop"> where the bus stops </button> </li>
    <li> <button id="bus_finish"> where the bus finishes     </button> </li>
  </ul>

</div>
<div class="mainSection">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>SEARCH RESULTS:</p>
    <div class="list">
      <table id="buses" border="2">

        <thead>
          <th>Bus</th>
          <th>Route</th>
          <th>Start</th>
          <th>Stop 1</th>
          <th>Stop 2</th>
          <th>Stop 3</th>
          <th>Stop 4</th>
          <th>Stop 5</th>
          <th>Finish</th>
          <th>Times</th>
          <th>Maps</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
      </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I am trying what you suggested but I still cannot get the list to change based on the button selection. I want each button to correspond to the relevant table header and only show what is in that column? how might I write a function to show a column based on the selected button?

Comment: so when you press a button, how do you know what to filter?